# Access Nextcloud Installed on Ubuntu Server 18.04

Tags: server, 18.04, nextcloud

I installed Nextcloud via snap on a Ubuntu Server 18.04. Everything was installed fine but I can't access it from any computer in my local network.

The tutorial I followed said that after the installation, I can just visit Nextcloud by using either the IP address of the server or the `localhost` address on my browser. In both cases I get a "Problem loading page" message.

What is happening? How can I access it?

Comment: Which tutorial you had use? What do you have in log files for NextCloud and web (www) service?

Comment: @mariaczi Well all the tutorial I found on google just say run `sudo snap install nextcloud` and after that go to`localhost` or IP of the server given that it is in the same network. I don't know how to see those log files though.